# How to form a LabeledPoint from another LabeledPoint replacing one of the values with random numbers in PySpark

Tags: python, random, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `LabeledPoint` `label1` which has values such as `(12,24)`,`(-21.3,-17.49)` and so on. No I want to form another `LabeledPoint` `label2` which will have the `1st value` as the `1st value` from `label1` but the second value should be at a random difference of `+2`or `-2` from the `1st value`. So like for `(12,24)` the `label2` should have `12` as `1st value` and for `2nd value` a random number between `10` to `14` (+2 and -2 from 12).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have an RDD of `LabeledPoints` and that when you refer to the '1st value` you are referring to the label and the second value you are referring to the feature(s)? By the way, as far as I'm aware, the features must be a list...

Anyways, will something like the following accomplish what you are looking for?

```
import random

rdd.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x.label, [i + random.choice([2, -2]) for i in x.features]))
```